# aren't sample space and subset of that sample space dependent?

Tags: probability, independence

Problem is following: Let $A$ be an event, a subset of the sample space $B$. Are $A$ and $B$ independent?

I found this exercise online and it said that $A$ and $B$ are independent but I don't think so because $P(A|B)=1$ which doesn't always equal to $P(A)$

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are independent if

$$\mathbf P[A\cap B]= \mathbf P[A]\mathbf P[B]\tag 1\label 1.$$

If $A\subset B, $ then

$$\mathbf P[A\cap B]= \mathbf P[A]\tag 2\label 2.$$

For $\eqref 1$ to hold in $\eqref 2,$ either $\mathbf P[B]=1$ when $\mathbf P[A]\ne 0$ or $\mathbf P[A]= 0.$